# Android Kishonti GFXBench: Starting a specific test from adb shell without navigating through the app's menus

Tags: android

Does anyone know if there is a way to fire up a specific test from the GFXBench suite directly from adb shell?

I have seen references on the net about a very similar command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a net.kishonti.testfw.ACTION_RUN_TESTS -n net.kishonti.gfxbench.vulkan.v50000.corporate/net.kishonti.benchui.corporate.CommandLineSession -e test_ids "gl_manhattan" --ei raw_config.single_frame 56400 --ei raw_config.max_rendered_frames 1 --es -screenshot_frames 0
```

but this does not seem to work with the current GFXBench application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you need to start the main activity first.
Have you tried

am start net.kishonti.gfxbench.vulkan.v50000.corporate/net.kishonti.app.MainActivity

Then sleep for a second to let the activity start, and then fire up the braodcast command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).