# Running GFXBench Offscreen using ADB

Tags: android, benchmarking

I have a prototype device running Android but with no screen. I want to benchmark its GPU using GFXBench.

Anyone know the ADB command to launch GFXBench v5.0 and a specific benchmark? As well as get the results. I've tried: [Android Kishonti GFXBench: Starting a specific test from adb shell without navigating through the app's menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72285611/android-kishonti-gfxbench-starting-a-specific-test-from-adb-shell-without-navig) but it doesn't seem to work with v5.0.

I can't even find the package that gfxbench belongs to. I installed it using:

```
> adb install GFXBench\ Benchmark_5.0.5_Apkpure.apk
> Performing Streamed Install
> Success
```

However, when looking for it with dumpsys:

```
dumpsys package | grep gfx
```

Returns nothing.